# Question on the plane curve definition

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

In my Differential Geometry course, it was given the following definition for the plane curves. But, I did some research, and I couldn't find something simillar in a book or on the internet. So, I am posting here so that you can write me your opinion.

I would like to ask what the definition above intuitively/geometrically means and if it's really useful if we do differential geometry.

> **Definition.** We call Plane Curve a subset of the Euclidean Space $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that it's covered by a number of parametrizations and
>   every point of the set has a neibourhood which is covered by a
>   parametrization.

Also, I have observed that almost all the DG books when they reffer to 'curve' they actually mean the 'parametrization of a curve'. What you think is the best?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems sloppy and vague to me. Are they specifying that the parametrizations map from open intervals in $\Bbb R$ by one-to-one smooth maps with nowhere-zero derivative?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, of course exactly this.

Comment: To be honest, in my differential geometry text and in most elementary texts, we just work with plane curves and space curves as parametrized curves (and usually assume, for theoretical reasons, an arclength parametrization — i.e., a parametrization with speed $1$).

Comment: So, if we  write 'curve' we actually mean the 'parametrization of a curve'. Right?

Comment: You can picture the curve as the *image* of the parametrization (i.e., the trace of the parametrization as time passes), but to work with this mathematically you ordinarily work with a parametrization, yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. And a last question: Do you know where can I find a book which contains this (complicated) definition?

Comment: It's a garbled version of defining a one-dimensional manifold in the plane. I don't know why your professor is doing this, but you should ask him/her for a reference.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.